# Imagecolorallocate array in php doesn't work

Tags: php, image, colors

First i made color variables like this :

```
$violet = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 238,130,238);
$orange = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255,165,0);
$red = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255,0,0);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 0,0,255);
$yellow = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255,255,0); 
$green = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 0,128,0);
$silver = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 192,192,192);
```

I'm planning to make lots of lines with various colour, so i made code like this :

```
$LIST_COLOR     = array($violet,$orange,$red,$blue,$yellow,$green,$silver);
```

Finally, i'm trying to make 7 lines using colors above using this code :

```
for($i=1; $i<=7; $i++)
{
    imageline($canvas, 50, 50, 150, 100*$i,$LIST_COLOR);
}
```

But there's no line at all. It's blank. I replaced $LIST_COLOR with $violet or other color variables, the color appeared. What's wrong with my code anyway?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the entire array `$LIST_COLOR` as a color rather than the current index `$LIST_COLOR[$i]`.

Also arrays start at 0, therefore you should use `for($i=0; $i<7; $i++)`.

Fixed code:

```
for($i=0; $i<7; $i++) {
    imageline($canvas, 50, 50, 150, 100*$i, $LIST_COLOR[$i]);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It may also be wise to count the total instead of using 7 arbitrarily .

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix True but I've set my expectations low. Also flagged question for off topic anyway.